# Need help in pointing application in the default website to have a domain name

Tags: windows, iis, domain-name

How to add an IP address to the virtual directory in IIS, for example i have pointed the domain name to the default website and it is pointing correctly, the issue i would to have a domain for the defaulvirtualdirectory/application(ex:www.xyz.com/abc) to have a domain name http://abc.def.com.

I tried all the possibilities like HTTP redirect but the problem is it is pointing to the default website instead of application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have website URL like http://abc.def.com to load web-contents of sub-directory e.g WWWROOT/application, you should add another subdomain website http://abc.def.com with documentroot as WWWROOT/application. The primary website(http://def.com) will load web-contents of WWWROOT and subdomain website(http://abc.def.com) will load webcontents of WWWROOT/application directory. You can also point subdomain website to different IP address if you want.